# Funeral for Varna Sankar वर्ण संकर?

Tags: scripture, varna, sraddha, funeral

How does a Varna Sankar perform funeral of his parents ?

Will they be stuck in preta yoni ? Can they be given Pind Daan ?

*Please give sashstra reference, as far as possible.*